# Sum all value in angular without controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

So I have a problem with Angular for 2 days, is there a way to sum all angular data without controller?

I want to print totalPrice from all subTotal, I tried to use method getTotalPrice() to sum in controller but I dont know how to pass the subTotal array

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   <div class="form-group" ng-init="qty_{{$product->id}}=0">

     {{Form::label($product->id, $product->name.' - '.$product->price, array('class'=>'col-md-4 control-label'))}}
     <input type="hidden" ng-model="price_{{$product->id}}" ng-init="price_{{$product->id}}={{$product->price}}">

     <div class="col-md-2">
       <input id="{{$product->id}}" type="number" min="0" value="0" step="1" class="form-control" name="qty_{{$product->id}}" ng-model='qty_{{$product->id}}'>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
       <label for="" class="col-md-10 control-label"><% qty_{{$product->id}} * {{$product->price}} %></label>
     </div>

   </div>
   <br>
@endforeach

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
      <label for="" class="col-md-6 control-label">Total Price</label>
      <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label" ng-model="totalPrice" ng-init="totalPrice = 0" ng-value="<% getTotalPrice() %>"><% getTotalPrice() %></label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Heres my current controller

```
myApp.controller('cashierController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.subTotal = [];
  $scope.getTotalPrice = function(subTotal) {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    for(sub in subTotal){
      totalPrice += sub;
    }
    return totalPrice;
  }
}]);
```

P.S : I use angular in laravel 
Sorry if there any weird codes, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post HTML, not PHP code.

Comment: you should add some button or something and add ng-click="getTotalPrice(totalPrice)"

Answer (score 0):

One way is to solve it with php/laravel:

just before @foreach add a new variable

```
<?php $grandTotal = 0 ?>
```

and within your foreach before totalPrice label

```
<?php grandTotal += $product->price  ?>
```

And inside label just echo it:

```
<label>{{ $grandTotal }}</label>  <!--or normal echo-->
```

**Second option**
Which is way cleaner, add a very simply route to return products as JSON file and $http get it from angular then pass it to your view, it will at least make things clearer to you (( you will use angular to handle and arrange FE views not handle everything via blade)).

```
Route::get('products/json','ProductsController@getAllJson');
```

inside ProductsController

```
public function getAllJson() {
//inject your repository above and use it here or simply use eloquent

return Product::all();

}
```

now inside your controller in angular just make simple $http get:

```
myApp.controller('cashierController', ['$scope,$http', function($scope,$http){

  $scope.products = [];
  $scope.grandTotal = 0;

  $http.get('products/json')
      .then(function(response){
    $scope.products = response.data;
       });

// there is no need for this function anymore since you've 2-way-binding
  $scope.getTotalPrice = function() {
    return totalPrice;
  }
}]);
```

finally, in your HTML use angular ng-repeat and that variable we've declared grandTotal.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" class="form-group">

<!-- Other content goes here for each product -->

<label for="" class="col-md-10 control-label">
@{{grandTotal}}
</label>

</div>
```